# IndentationError: unindent does not match

Tags: python-3.x

```
import random
def getAnswer(answerNumber):
     if answerNumber == 1:
           return 'It is certain'
       elif answerNumber == 2:
           return 'It is decidedly so'
       elif answerNumber == 3:
           return 'Yes'
       elif answerNumber == 4:
           return 'Reply hazy try again'
       elif answerNumber == 5:
           return 'Ask again later'
       elif answerNumber == 6:
           return 'Concentrate and ask again'
       elif answerNumber == 7:
           return 'My reply is no'
       elif answerNumber == 8:
           return 'Outlook not so good'
       elif answerNumber == 9:
           return 'Very doubtful'

r = random.randint(1, 9)
fortune = getAnswer(r)
print(fortune)
```

Comment: Veryyyyy Thanks !! I am veryyyy new in Python....

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! If one of the answer below helped you to solve your problem, please mark it as ["accepted"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) to help futur readers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have too many spaces before the "elif" keyword, try this:

```
import random
def getAnswer(answerNumber):
     if answerNumber == 1:
           return 'It is certain'
     elif answerNumber == 2:
           return 'It is decidedly so'
     elif answerNumber == 3:
           return 'Yes'
     elif answerNumber == 4:
           return 'Reply hazy try again'
     elif answerNumber == 5:
           return 'Ask again later'
     elif answerNumber == 6:
           return 'Concentrate and ask again'
     elif answerNumber == 7:
           return 'My reply is no'
     elif answerNumber == 8:
           return 'Outlook not so good'
     elif answerNumber == 9:
           return 'Very doubtful'

r = random.randint(1, 9)
fortune = getAnswer(r)
print(fortune)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to indent your `elif` on the same level as the `if`.